# Vertica SQL - Converting rank number to own column

Tags: sql, pivot, window-functions, rank, vertica

I have the following data (example) ranked in a CTE table;

## [image: ID Value Rank 1 10 1 1 20 2 1 30 3 2 10 1 2 25 2 2 35 3]

I'd like to, from my main query, have a new column per rank with the value; maintaining just one row per ID.

I can get it to have 3 rows per ID with nulls filling the gaps but cannot find the solution to get 1 row per ID.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
with t_cte as (
    select id, value, row_number() over(partition by id order by value) rn
    from mytable)
select ID, max(case when rn=1 then [Value] else 0 end) Rank1,
           max(case when rn=2 then [Value] else 0 end) Rank2,
           max(case when rn=3 then [Value] else 0 end) Rank3
from t_cte
group by ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select
    id,
    max(case when rn = 1 then value end) value1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then value end) value2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then value end) value3
from (
    select id, value, row_number() over(partition by id order by value) rn
    from mytable
) t
group by id
```